# Apache ignoring rewrite rules with AllowOverride=All and Rewrite module enabled

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, amazon-linux

I'm setting up an Apache instance in an Amazon linux 2 docker container but I can't get URLs past the root URL to rewrite to Laravel's `index.php` properly, I've tried every solution I can find (info listed below) but nothing has worked so far.

For the sake of testing this everything in `/var/www/html/mysite` is `apache:apache` with 777 permissions.

I'm using Apache 2.4.34

Going to `/` works fine but going to any URL beyond that like `/auth/login` 403 errors, checking the error log I can see it's not re-writing and is trying to read the file directly from the document root

```
[core:error] AH00035: access to /auth/login denied (filesystem path '/var/www/html/mysite/public/auth') because search permissions are missing on a component of the path
```

I know the `.htaccess` file is being read because putting a syntax error in it shows up the "Internal server error" page as expected, here is my `.htaccess` file (inside `/var/www/html/mysite/public`).

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

httpd.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/mysite/public

        <Directory /var/www/html/mysite/public>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride All
                Require all granted
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

httpd -M output

```
Loaded Modules:
 core_module (static)
 so_module (static)
 http_module (static)
 access_compat_module (shared)
 actions_module (shared)
 alias_module (shared)
 allowmethods_module (shared)
 auth_basic_module (shared)
 auth_digest_module (shared)
 authn_anon_module (shared)
 authn_core_module (shared)
 authn_dbd_module (shared)
 authn_dbm_module (shared)
 authn_file_module (shared)
 authn_socache_module (shared)
 authz_core_module (shared)
 authz_dbd_module (shared)
 authz_dbm_module (shared)
 authz_groupfile_module (shared)
 authz_host_module (shared)
 authz_owner_module (shared)
 authz_user_module (shared)
 autoindex_module (shared)
 cache_module (shared)
 cache_disk_module (shared)
 cache_socache_module (shared)
 data_module (shared)
 dbd_module (shared)
 deflate_module (shared)
 dir_module (shared)
 dumpio_module (shared)
 echo_module (shared)
 env_module (shared)
 expires_module (shared)
 ext_filter_module (shared)
 filter_module (shared)
 headers_module (shared)
 include_module (shared)
 info_module (shared)
 log_config_module (shared)
 logio_module (shared)
 macro_module (shared)
 mime_magic_module (shared)
 mime_module (shared)
 negotiation_module (shared)
 remoteip_module (shared)
 reqtimeout_module (shared)
 request_module (shared)
 rewrite_module (shared)
 setenvif_module (shared)
 slotmem_plain_module (shared)
 slotmem_shm_module (shared)
 socache_dbm_module (shared)
 socache_memcache_module (shared)
 socache_shmcb_module (shared)
 status_module (shared)
 substitute_module (shared)
 suexec_module (shared)
 unique_id_module (shared)
 unixd_module (shared)
 userdir_module (shared)
 version_module (shared)
 vhost_alias_module (shared)
 watchdog_module (shared)
 dav_module (shared)
 dav_fs_module (shared)
 dav_lock_module (shared)
 lua_module (shared)
 mpm_prefork_module (shared)
 proxy_module (shared)
 lbmethod_bybusyness_module (shared)
 lbmethod_byrequests_module (shared)
 lbmethod_bytraffic_module (shared)
 lbmethod_heartbeat_module (shared)
 proxy_ajp_module (shared)
 proxy_balancer_module (shared)
 proxy_connect_module (shared)
 proxy_express_module (shared)
 proxy_fcgi_module (shared)
 proxy_fdpass_module (shared)
 proxy_ftp_module (shared)
 proxy_http_module (shared)
 proxy_hcheck_module (shared)
 proxy_scgi_module (shared)
 proxy_uwsgi_module (shared)
 proxy_wstunnel_module (shared)
 systemd_module (shared)
 cgi_module (shared)
 http2_module (shared)
 proxy_http2_module (shared)
```

sestatus output `SELinux status:                 disabled`

Comment: Are you accessing your site over HTTPS? Remove the `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>` wrapper. Apache isn't necessarily "ignoring rewrite rules" - you would appear to have a _permissions_ issue of some kind.

Comment: @MrWhite No the docker container's port 80 is bound to my machine's port 8080 so I'm accessing it via http://localhost:8080